# Injecting sessionFactory into grails service when calling from a groovy script

Tags: hibernate, grails, sessionfactory

I have a grails service:

```
MyService {   
   def sessionFactory    
   void someMethod() {
     //...
     sessionFactory.currentSession.createSQLQuery(sql);
     //...    
   } 
}
```

I want to invoke this service from a groovy script (located in src/groovy). Im invoking via the grails command - grails test run-script src\groovy\CallMyService.groovy.

The sessionFactory is null when called this way (it works fine when run as an integration test). But I would like to invoke it via a script. How can I inject the sessionFactory into the service? I tried modifying the RunScript.groovy, for eg like this:

```
def sessionFactory = appCtx.getBean("sessionFactory")
def session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, true)
TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, new SessionHolder(session))
```

but that didnt help. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a script run with `run-script`, you should be able to get your service with:

```
myService = ctx.myService
```

If spring is managing your service, the `sessionFactory` should be initialized automatically.

Comment: That was it. In fact I didnt need to modify the RunScript with the TransactionSynchronizationManager etc. (using Grails 2.1.0).